# Sort by product name not working as expected

Tags: magento2.3, product-sorting

I've bunch of products, Which names start with word "Bai" and afterwards some digits.

> Like, Bai-10, Bai-11, Bai-15 etc.

I've set Default product listing sort by to "use config setting" and at global level I've set it to "Product Name".

When I visit category page, I can see something like this.

[image]

Take a look at second row after **Bai-10**, **Bai-14** should come but **Bai-103** comes up.

Has anybody faced this type of issue ? Looks like its small thing but I'm not getting it.

Any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: please reindexing and flush caching after check and also check Log File.

Answer (score 3):

That is lexicographic sorting which means basically the language treats the variables as strings and compares character by character `"200"` is greater than `"19999"` because `'2'` is greater than `'1'`.
So in your case **Bai-10**, **Bai-103**, then **Bai-14** because of **`Bai-10`** is common and then again sorting is check so 0 (`03` Bai-103) is come before (`4` Bai-14).

The sorting is strictly alphabetical (and happens *left-to-right*, *one character* at a time): **1, 2, 10** makes sense to you but not to a computer that only knows alphabetic comparison. There's no way in that kind of simple comparison to know that a one followed by a **`0`** actually comes after a **`four`**.

Comment: nice answer.!!!! keep posting answer bro..!

Comment: I would suggest parsing the sort field into two separate ones. The first, obviously alphabetical, the second, numerical, preferably integer based.